# Why will my UILabel object not show in its superview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, subview

I have this subclass of UIView, which created a UILabel object and adds it as a subview. The code is below. I place a UIView object on a view controller's view, and I set the subclass to my subclass UTIDropDownView. When I run the app on a device, I am able to see the line that I draw, but I don't see the UILabel object.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class UTIDropDownView: UIView {

    var label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let labelFrame = CGRect(width: frame.width - frame.height, height: frame.height)

        label = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        addSubview(label)

        label.text = "UTIDropDownView"

        label.isHidden = false
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: frame.height).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let labelWidth: CGFloat = frame.width - frame.height
        let triangleBorder: CGFloat = frame.height * 0.1

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        UIColor.darkGray.setStroke()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: labelWidth + triangleBorder, y: triangleBorder))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - triangleBorder, y: triangleBorder))
        path.stroke()

    }

}
```

When I add the following code in draw(_:)

```
print(rect)
```

I get the following print results:

> (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 30.0)

Comment: Use the View Hierarchy debugger to dump the view hierarchy and see where your label is. Maybe it's somewhere offscreen for some reason?

Comment: Can you also check the sizes you are initialising the view with? With your size calculation for the label it could be possible the width is below 0.

Comment: @Rudedog I don't know how to use the View Hierarchy debugger to dump the view hierarchy. How do you do that?

The width is 120 and the height is 30, as I set it in Interface Builder.

Comment: @Marcel The width is 120 and the height is 30, as I set it in Interface Builder.

Comment: I added the code to print rect in draw(_:) and the debug print results show a legitimate rect. I updated the question with this information.

Comment: Ah! There it is. I printed the label.frame in draw(_:) and it prints as (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0).

Comment: When you are using interface builder init() doesn't get called, only `init?(coder:)`

Comment: @Marcel Is there a way to use code to check if I'm using interface builder?

Comment: What you could do is put the code that configures and adds the label in a separate method and call that method from both `init(frame:)` and `init?(coder:)`, that way you know for sure the code gets executed.

Comment: @Marcel Thank you for your help. I got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `draw(_ rect:)`, but are not actually drawing the label in that function. You could call `super.draw(rect)` in your draw method to have the view first draw its content, and then you draw your custom stuff after that.

```
class UTIDropDownView: UIView {

let label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupLabel()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupLabel()
}

private func setupLabel() {
    let labelFrame = CGRect(width: frame.width - frame.height, height: frame.height)

    label.frame = labelFrame

    addSubview(label)

    label.text = "UTIDropDownView"

    label.isHidden = false
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: frame.height).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    ...
}
```

}

Comment: I added "super.draw(rect)" as the first line of code of the draw(_:) method, and it didn't fix the problem. It's still showing like it did before.